# Makefile rebuilds all files even if only one changes

Tags: makefile

I am writing a Makefile for a project with a large number of js files in a complex directory structure. When run it needs to perform some compilation on each file and save the results to a different directory with the same tree structure (right now that's simulated by a `cp`). When I run `make js` it builds as it should and when I run `make js` again it says that there is no work to do. However when I modify one of the files and `make js` it re-builds the entire tree instead of just the modified file.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
BUILDDIR := build/gui/

RAWJSFILES := $(shell find app -name '*.js')
BUILT_RAWJSFILES := $(patsubst %, $(BUILDDIR)%,$(RAWJSFILES))

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)

$(RAWJSFILES): $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILT_RAWJSFILES): $(RAWJSFILES)
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    # compile step
    cp $(shell python -c "print '$@'.lstrip('${BUILDDIR}')") $(@D)

.PHONY: js
js: $(BUILT_RAWJSFILES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$(BUILT_RAWJSFILES): $(RAWJSFILES)` is setting the prerequisites of *each file* in `$(BUILT_RAWJSFILES)` to **all** the files in `$(RAWJSFILES)`.

To get the one-to-one mapping you want you need a pattern rule or a static pattern rule.

Also that embedded python snippet isn't *at all* doing what you intended for it to do there. It is removing the longest leading prefix from the value of `$@` that contains any of the characters in `BUILDDIR` namely `build/gui/` (only not as a string as characters so that's equivalent to `lstrip('/iugdlb')`). (Oh, also you don't need `$(shell)` here you are already in a shell context so a normal command substitution would work just as well (`$$(python ...)`.)

That being said if you use a pattern or static pattern rule you'll have easier ways to get the source filename then messing with python like that.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
$(BUILDDIR)%.js: %.js
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        cp $^ $(@D)
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for clearing that up! Your example also worked exactly as advertised.